# How can i read the contents from a text file as a string in Nuxt (or Vue)?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

Id like to read the contents of a text file which i have imported in my *.vue* file like `import ToS from '~/static/terms-of-service.txt';`

I want to access the contents as a String.

How can I do it?

Comment: what is the build system you are using?

Answer (score 19):

**VUE CLI 3**

1. First install the raw loader
   `npm install raw-loader --save-dev`
2. If you don't have a **vue.config.js**, make one at root and add

   ```
   module.exports = {
     chainWebpack: config => {
       config.module
         .rule('raw')
         .test(/\.txt$/)
         .use('raw-loader')
         .loader('raw-loader')
         .end()
     }
   }
   ```
3. To get the text file as string (if placed in **src/assets/txt/**):
   `import file from '@/assets/txt/file.txt'`

N.B. Remember to rebuild

Answer (score 10):

I'm using nuxt (created with vue cli 3), and this is what worked for me:

1. `npm install --save-dev raw-loader`
2. Update `nuxt.config.js`

```
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {

      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.txt$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      });

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader

Seems that you need a loader to read files in vue