# Read a file content as a string in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vite

Some other post respond to the same problem ([here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/importing-text-file-as-string-in-vue-cli-3/37784), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896177/how-can-i-read-the-contents-from-a-text-file-as-a-string-in-nuxt-or-vue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697757/read-file-inside-current-directory-using-vue)) by using raw-loader but from my understanding it is deprecated for webpack v5 (but I'm not sure if it's relevant for Vue).

Also when I tried using it my file got loaded as a path :
for example doing `import file from '/src/assets/article.txt'` creates a variable named 'file' containing the path as a String.

Answer (score 1):

You're right `raw-loader` has been deprecated in Webpack 5. You should use [`Asset Modules`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead.

> Asset Modules type replaces all of these loaders by adding 4 new module types:
>
> - `asset/source` exports the source code of the asset. Previously achievable by using `raw-loader`.

Here is an example of the `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {       
         test: /\.txt/,
         type: 'asset/source',
        }
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

I tested it on a vanilla Vue 3 project installed with Vue CLI. It worked perfectly.

Comment: My problem is that I think I use Asset Modules right for loading .txt files as strings, here is my vue.config.js file for example :
`const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.txt/,
       type: 'asset/source'
     }
   ]
 },
};
`
but doing `import text from '/src/assets/article.txt'` still gets me a String variable named text containing the path and not the content of the file.

Comment: I think your `vue.config.js` syntax might be incorrect. I updated my answer to show an example configuration.

Comment: After copying your `vue.config.js` it's still not getting me the content of the file. Could this perhaps have to do with the fact that I created the project with Vite instead of with Vue CLI ? Thanks for your help

Comment: [https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html](This) actually fixed my problem as I was working with Vite and not Vue CLI, thanks for your help still.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you were able to sort it out :)